# Android ListFragmentIssue

Tags: android

I got a FragmentActivity with 2 ListFragments, Every time I swype beteen them, a layout progress begins and causes getView on the adapter for all visible items. How can I avoid this behavior?

I got 7 visible items in my list, and getView occuers too many times... (400 times when app starts)

Any suggestions?

Comment: cant you use `viewholder` i.e. `setTag()` `getTag()`?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you maintain someone else code and he is using ListFragment Make sure he didn't override the onCreateViewRoot method!!!